# HTML sup tag with absolute position renders incorrectly

Tags: html, css

I'd like to place line numbers periodically to the left of a block of indented text. My idea was to have a `<span>` per line with padding to the left (see `"poetry"` class), then absolutely position a `<sup>` element for the line number. However, I'm experiencing a strange rendering bug in Firefox. It seems as if the absolutely positioned `<sup>` is placed at an incorrect height, but if I go into the developer panel and change something, the `<sup>` suddenly gets placed correctly.

This is represented in the gif below. The first line, marked with `1` shows a block of regular, non-indented text for reference. The second line starts with a `2` that is initially incorrectly positioned. The second `2` that is not absolutely positioned is there for reference to show what I would expect the y offset to be. Going into the developer panel and changing the `left` attribute suddenly updates the absolutely positioned `2`.

However, even the updated position still doesn't look quite right; it looks like it gets placed a little higher than the second `2`.

[image: Firefox rendering bug?]

Here is my example HTML file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        body {
            max-width: 900px;
            /* margin: 0 auto !important; */
            /* float: none !important; */
            line-height: 1.5em;
        }

        .poetry {
            position: relative;
            padding-left: 2em;
        }

        .poetry .linenum {
            display: inline;
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <span>
        <sup class="linenum">1</sup> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </span>
    <br>
    <span class="poetry">
        <sup class="linenum">2</sup> <sup>2</sup>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </span>
</body>
```

**Any thoughts to why this is happening and how I can fix it?**

Answer (score 0):

Don't nest the `sup` in the `poetry` `span`.

```css
        body {
            max-width: 900px;
            /* margin: 0 auto !important; */
            /* float: none !important; */
            line-height: 1.5em;
        }

        .poetry {
            position: relative;
            padding-left: 2em;
        }
```

```html
<body>
    <span>
        <sup class="linenum">1</sup> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </span>
    <br> 
    <sup class="linenum">2</sup>
    <span class="poetry">
        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </span>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the margin-right property for the sup:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        body {
            max-width: 900px;
            /* margin: 0 auto !important; */
            /* float: none !important; */
            line-height: 1.5em;
        }
        .poetry .linenum {
            display: inline;
            margin-right: 2em;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <span>
        <sup class="linenum">1</sup> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </span>
    <br>
    <span class="poetry">
        <sup class="linenum">2</sup>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </span>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use ordered lists and modify it according to your own preference?

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <style>
          body {
            max-width: 900px;
            /* margin: 0 auto !important; */
            /* float: none !important; */
            line-height: 1.5em;
          }
      
          ol li {
            margin: 0 0 30px 0;
          }
          ol li span {
            margin-top: 5px;
            position: absolute;
            padding-left: 1rem;
          }
          ol {
            counter-reset: item;
            list-style-type: none;
          }
          ol li {
            display: block;
          }
          ol li:before {
            content: counter(item) "  ";
            counter-increment: item;
          }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <ol>
          <li>
            <span>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
              eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
            </span>
          </li>
          <li>
            <span>
              Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
              nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
            </span>
          </li>
        </ol>
      </body>
    </html>
```